# Como cambiar el valor de un slider usando javascript?

Tags: javascript

El codigo en html es asi:

```
<div class="slider-selection" style="left: 0%; width: 49.4845%;"></div>
```

Lo que intentaba era basicamente cambiar el valor usando con javascript, para un input hago lo siguiente para cambiar su valor:

```
$("input[name=example]").focus().val(0.1).blur();
```

Pero de un slider como puedo cambiar su valor usando javascript? Alguien sabria como?

Image del slider:
http://prntscr.com/oi40b4

El slider completo yo lo que quiero es editar el valor del slider usando javascript obviamente es un html como cualquier otro.

```
<div class="slider-track"><div class="slider-track-low" style="left: 0px; width: 0%;"></div><div class="slider-selection" style="left: 0%; width: 54.6392%;"></div><div class="slider-track-high" style="right: 0px; width: 45.3608%;"></div><div class="slider-handle min-slider-handle round" tabindex="0" style="left: 54.6392%;"></div><div class="slider-handle max-slider-handle round hide" tabindex="0" style="left: 0%;"></div></div>
```

Quiero usar algun codigo desde consola para cambiar su valor. Me refiero a la consola developer tools de chrome para introducir un nuevo valor en el slider.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so], te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta no está clara. Hablas de *slider*, pero no indicas el plugin o framework con el que trabajas. Además cuando hablas de *cambiar el valor* ¿a qué valor te refieres con exactitud?. Por favor, si crees que puedes modificar tu pregunta para agregarle más información, puedes hacer clic en [edit]. Saludos

Comment: Actualmente no estás publicando la manera en que has probado, tampoco el contenido del slider, te recomiendo que leas el comentario de arriba para poder que la comunidad te ofrezca una buena ayuda.

Comment: Puedo poner una imagen del slider o un link de referencia

Comment: ¿Es posible que publiques todo el snippet de tu código en la pregunta o en JSFiddle o CodePen? Lo que observo es que no es un input type range, sino un div estilizado con CSS, para poder darte una buena respuesta requiero ver como funciona actualmente.

Comment: Es de esta pagina simplemente queria cambiar el valor del slider por curiosidad la pagina es southxchange.com/Home/Dice y debe estar registrado. De todas maneras creo que es solo posible con selenium.

Comment: Lee la documentación de https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/

Comment: Si lo lei pero en el ejemplo no consigo cambiar el valor desde consola

Comment: Hola? Puedes ayudarme pprfa