# Como cambiar el valor de un div estilizado desde consola usando javascript?

Tags: javascript

Lo que queria basicamente es desde la consola de herramientas al desarrollo de chrome poder cambiar su valor usando algun codigo en javascript tal como:

```
$("div[name=example]").focus().val(10).blur();
```

Obviamente este codigo no me funciono. Cual seria la manera correcta de alterar el valor de este div estilizado que aparenta ser un slider desde la consola:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Basicamente el div estilizado que aparenta ser un slider es el siguiente .

```css
element.style {
}
.dice.panel .slider.slider-horizontal {
    width: calc(100% - 20px) !important;
}
.slider.slider-horizontal {
    width: 210px;
    height: 20px;
}
.slider {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
}
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheet
div {
    display: block;
}
Inherited from td.text-center
.table>tbody>tr>td, .table>tbody>tr>th, .table>tfoot>tr>td, .table>tfoot>tr>th, .table>thead>tr>td, .table>thead>tr>th {
    padding: 8px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.text-center {
    text-align: center;
}
Inherited from table.table.table-bordered.table-status
.table {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
user agent stylesheet
table {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    border-color: grey;
}
Inherited from body
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #f5f7fa;
    font-family: roboto;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
body {
    font-family: helvetica neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
}
Inherited from html.js.flexbox.flexboxlegacy.canvas.canvastext.webgl.no-touch.geolocation.postmessage.websqldatabase.indexeddb.hashchange.history.draganddrop.websockets.rgba.hsla.multiplebgs.backgroundsize.borderimage.borderradius.boxshadow.textshadow.opacity.cssanimations.csscolumns.cssgradients.cssreflections.csstransforms.csstransforms3d.csstransitions.fontface.generatedcontent.video.audio.localstorage.sessionstorage.webworkers.applicationcache.svg.inlinesvg.smil.svgclippaths
html {
    font-size: 10px;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
Pseudo ::before element
:after, :before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
Pseudo ::after element
:after, :before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
Pseudo ::scrollbar element
div::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
}
Pseudo ::scrollbar-thumb element
div::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #cbd2d6;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider slider-horizontal" id=""><div class="slider-track"><div class="slider-track-low" style="left: 0px; width: 0%;"></div><div class="slider-selection" style="left: 0%; width: 70.1031%;"></div><div class="slider-track-high" style="right: 0px; width: 29.8969%;"></div><div class="slider-handle min-slider-handle round" tabindex="0" style="left: 70.1031%;"></div><div class="slider-handle max-slider-handle round hide" tabindex="0" style="left: 0%;"></div></div><div class="tooltip tooltip-main top hide" style="left: 70.1031%; margin-left: 0px;"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner">60</div></div><div class="tooltip tooltip-min top hide"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner"></div></div><div class="tooltip tooltip-max top hide"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner"></div></div></div>
```

Mi pregunta hay alguna manera de cambiar su valor? O la unica manera es usando selenium para este tipo de cosas? Algun codigo en javascript que solucione de manera simple como editar el valor del div.

Comment: ¿Posible duplicado de una pregunta de hace 15 horas [Como cambiar el valor de un slider usando javascript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/280484/como-cambiar-el-valor-de-un-slider-usando-javascript)?

Comment: ¿Podrías arreglar el snippet para que se vea el slider al que te refieres? También puedes pasar un enlace de la fuente de donde has sacado el slider.

Comment: la fuente es la misma solamente intentaba pero no consegui resolverlo